# Cassandra- is there a safe way to change UDT's which are already duplicated with data in other tables?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, user-defined-types

using cassandra database 3.4 and the datastax dev center, we have 3 nodes.

we had to change some of our udt's a number of times in development.
a change example is:
"CREATE TYPE my_type (
    id int,
    name text,
    description text
);"

and after it's already created and used in all sorts of table add a field for example:
"created_time timestamp"

once we change a UDT **some** of our tables data becomes corrupted.
the error we get is

"unable to execute CQL script on 'database': cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE(1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)"

we tried restarting the cassandra and running repair.
but some data will always stay corrupted. **new data will always be OK**

is there a safe way to change UDT's which are already duplicated with data in other tables?

thank you

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: The error msg *unable to execute CQL script on 'database': cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE(1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)* just says that some of your replica(s) are not available. It does not say anything about UDT corruption. Can you show more details logs in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` ?

Comment: I'm using cassandra 3.4, and I realize the message itself does not mean corruption but it shows consistently at certain "broken" points. for instance after the last change we found that in a very specific query from a table it always fails.